# css, images and vendor folders do not load when using htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Below is the htaccess scripti am using:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^gecko/([^/]*)$ gecko.php?gecko=$1 [L]
```

Which changes `http://localhost/geckology/gecko.php?gecko=Zilly` (which loads css etc fine) to  `http://localhost/geckology/gecko/zilly` which doesn't load the css etc fine as it looking in directories like this `http://localhost/geckology/gecko/css/theme.css` when it should be `http://localhost/geckology/css/theme.css`

The site is huge, so if possible i would like a htaccess way of fixing this, however i will change everything to absolute urls if it's not possible

Comment: You forgot to post the real error messages you get on network (protocol) level. Open a browsers development console and check the (sub-) requests made. Post the result. Also, you _obviously_ should consolt the error log file on the server file.

Comment: @arkascha i have, i've said the error is that it is loading from the `/gecko/` directory when it should be loading from the root directory

Comment: so not `geckology/gecko/css` it should be just `geckology/css`

Comment: OK, I did not clearly read that from the question. Anyways, that looks like you are using relative links for the stuff like css and images, which is fine. However you then have to prevent those links to be rewritten if you are using such a general rewrite rule. So you need exceptions from the rule. For example exceptions for a links pointing to an url ending in ''.css'. You can use the `RewriteCond` command for that.

Comment: Fair enough, though it does say that in the last line of the first paragraph. I'll have a look at RewriteCond but this is all new to me

Comment: `.htaccess`style files are the last resort anyways. You should always prefer other solutions, except when no such "clean" solution is left. `.htaccess` style files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and really slow the server down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the relative URI base by simply adding this to the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/" />
```

or if you have to use htaccess, which is really inefficient and will assume all of your css/scripts/etc are all in one place, while at the same time making the rest of the world think the same thing is actually 2 different URLs:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^gecko/(css|images|other)(/.*)$ /$1/$2 [L]
```

This blindly rewrites any URL that tries to access "css", "image" or "other" folders within the /gecko/ path.

Comment: thank you Jon, this has worked perfectly. Really appreciate your honesty and help on this :)